Magic Chef Oven Starting
Where do I find the model number on a 1998 era fifth wheel type Magic Chef propane stove?
I need to find a manual as all top burners ignite no problems but oven needs to be lighted by a long cigarette lighter.

Nothing on inside of door so must be on back of stove. What part could be bad as nothing changes pushing in button at all? How to upload a picture or two to this site?``

Quite often they are on the backside of the oven/stove/anything on a metal label.

A picture or two may help - perhaps someone will recognize the type of oven.
